# Supporting Right to Left languages

Tags: android, localization, right-to-left

How can I localize my application to support some Right to Left languages?
How can I localize my application to support Hebrew? Arabic? and other languages?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your friend for general purposes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

If you want input support:

http://code.google.com/p/android-hebkey/

http://www.thesea.ae/blog/?p=53

Otherwise, I *think* at the moment there is no support to have the app written(text on the screen) in either of those without a 3rd plug-in.